# Chart.js will not render using vue.js until window resizes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, chart.js, vue.js

I have a simple app that uses Bootstrap, vue.js, and chart.js. The HTML template is pretty simple. I've noticed while searching for my error that this issue is often caused when trying to render a chart in a tab or modal but I don't have my chart in a modal or tab.

As soon as a I resize my browser window, the chart renders properly and scales to fit the div and everything.

For whatever reason, when the page first loads, the canvas HTML tag renders like this:

```
<canvas id="graph" width="0" height="0" style="margin: auto; width: 0px; display: block; height: 0px;"></canvas>
```

But when I resize the window, everything changes and I see the chart properly.

```
<canvas id="graph" width="493" height="328" style="margin: auto; width: 493px; display: block; height: 328px;"></canvas>
```

Why doesn't it get the height & width correct on page load?

**HTML Template**

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">Chart List</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <defaultchart>
                </defaultchart>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <chartlistview
                    :data="{{ $private }}"
                    :columns="{{ json_encode($columns) }}"
                >
                </chartlistview>
            </div>
        </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

**DefaultChart.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <canvas 
      id="graph" 
      v-el:canvas 
      width="600" 
      height="400" 
      style="margin:auto; width: 600px;"
    ></canvas>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {

    data() {
      return {
        ourChart: '',
        chartData: {
          labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
          datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3]
          }]
        }
      };
    },

    ready() {

      this.drawChart();     
    },

    methods: {

      drawChart: function() {

        if (this.ourChart) {
          this.ourChart.destroy();
        }
        var context = document.querySelector('#graph').getContext('2d');
        this.ourChart = new Chart(context, {
          type: 'line',
          data: this.chartData
          // wouldn't render at all with this regardless of resizing
          /*options: {
            response: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false
          }*/
        });

        // added these lines to see if it would fix the issue; it didn't
        this.ourChart.render();
        this.ourChart.update();
      }

    }
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing DOM in `ready()` is tricky, because Vue updates DOM asynchronously, so changes may have not been completely applied yet, and/or the browser has not yet done a new layout.

use `$nextTick()` to defer until the update has been completed:

```
ready() {
  this.$nextTick(function() {
    this.drawChart();     
  })
},
```

This *usually* does the trick in these situations, at least on the Vue side of things. Can't say much about the chart.js config.

Comment: Wow, that worked. Thanks! Question though. Is this a bug in Vue? I would think the `ready()` method would work just as it does in jQuery. Or was I using it wrong and I should always use `$nextTick` ?

Comment: No, it's not a bug in Vue. As I said, Vue [updates the DOM asynchronously](http://vuejs.org/guide/reactivity.html#Async-Update-Queue) for perfomance reasons, which means that when Vue says "put this element in the DOM", and fires the ready() hook afterwards, "this element" might not be in the DOM yet.

Since this is one of the most common pitfalls that people seem to come across, I will suggest to add it to the docs more prominently.

Comment: OK that makes sense. I was operating under the assumption that Vue was listening for an event callback from the browser on when the DOM was actually ready.